# Correlation in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk

I have 2 orchestrations in my project and 2 schemas (the first is for request, the second is for response).
`Orchestration 1` has a `Receive` shape (Activating=true). It receives a request and then routes it to `Orchestration 2`. The latter constructs a request to a web service, which responds with a response, waits 2 min and then sends a new request to my BizTalk service. Both projects use the same schemas, a `Request` and a `Response` schemas.

`Orchestration 2` uses a correlation set which is initialized in a `Send` shape that sends a request to the web service. Also, `Orchestration 2` has a `Receive` shape waiting for a message with the correlation set previously in the `Send` shape.

Here is the sequence diagram:
[image]

And there is the `Orchestration 2`:
[image]

`Send_1` and `Receive_2` shapes have correlation properties set up.

The problem is when a webservice sends request2 (see the diagram above) to my biztalk service, it throws an error saying **"The message found multiple request response subscriptions. A message can only be routed to a single request response subscription."** How that can be if I've set the correlation? I expected request2 to be routed to the `Orchestration 2` because it has a receiver with correlation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is correct.

When a Request is sent from the WebService, it is routed to the Activation Receive Shape of Orchestration2.

But because the correlation is in effect, this creates an additional subscription which is why the request is also expected to be routed to the third Receive shape in Orchestration2.

If you cannot distinguish the Request schemas, you must use an additionnal condition for activating Orchestration2. You can, for instance, filter the Request that comes from the Orchestration1 with extra filters based upon context properties.

You'll observe that one Request comes from an WCF or SOAP Adapter while the first one does not.

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks! I set up the Filter expression in the Receive shape of Orchestration 1 and so I got the whole thing working.